# Timestamp format with carriage return

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have this time stamp format:

```
var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Which produced a result like:

```
5/25/2019 10:52:43
```

but I would like to have a carriage return between the date and time for this result:

```
5/25/2019 
10:52:43
```

How might I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, guessing just works!

```
var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd\nHH:mm:ss";
```